# MySQL Mirroring or Triggers for duplicating data

Tags: mysql, triggers, mirroring

I am developing an PHP/JavaScript application to access the data saved by another application. I cannot connect the database cause of the possible slowdown induced in the MySQL engine. I am evaluating the possibilities instead of direct database connection. My question is what is better, complete MySQL Mirroring against on every CREATE, UPDATE or DELETE launch a trigger that copy the operation on the second database?

It is not important the difficult or quantity of work, is important the final performance.

Comment: Use a Master Slave Replication to do this. You can config this to replicate only some tables or Databases. So you only write in your Master Server. This will not slow down any write to the Master and starts automatic if the network or Slave was dowm

Comment: Thanks a lot @BerndBuffen for your reply. I will do as you say, thanks again (if you post an answer instead a comment I can put an acceptation)